# Plotting points with conditionals and adding colors to them

Tags: r, plot, conditional-statements

I´m trying to plot a scatter with two conditions at same: first one is if some observations are less than a value then plot with color green, second is if some observatios are more than a value then plot with red.

I would like my scatter with all the observations but showing me the selected with the colors I said. This is what I´m getting:

[image]

This is my code:

```
VALCMODEL2R=runif(50,1,100)
VALCMODEL2=runif(50,-30,20)
NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES=runif(50,0,0.004)
RMideT=data.frame(VALCMODEL2R,VALCMODEL2,NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES)

with(RMideT[(RMideT$VALCMODEL2R > 50) & (RMideT$VALCMODEL2R < 6),], 
plot(RMideT$VALCMODEL2, RMideT$NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES,col=2:3))
abline(h = median(RMideT$NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES), col="red", lwd=3, 
lty=2)
abline(v = 0, col="blue", lwd=3, lty=2)
```

Comment: Full reproducible example including some sample data would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

at the first step I made a table as a example, but you should read your data and save it as a data.frame:

```
VALCMODEL2R=runif(50,1,100)
VALCMODEL2=runif(50,-30,20)
NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES=runif(50,0,0.004)
RMideT=data.frame(VALCMODEL2R,VALCMODEL2,NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES)
```

filter data based on `RMideT$VALCMODEL2R` value

```
up=RMideT[(RMideT$VALCMODEL2R > 50) ,]#filter group 1 and name it up
down=RMideT[ (RMideT$VALCMODEL2R < 6), ]#filter group 2  and name it down
```

plot group 1 with color red

```
plot(up$VALCMODEL2, up$NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES,col="red")
```

add group 2 with color green to the previous plot

```
points(down$VALCMODEL2, down$NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES,col="green")
```

add abline to the previous plot

```
 abline(h = median(RMideT$NUEVO.CONOCIMIENTO.DOCENTES), col="red", lwd=3, 
           lty=2)

abline(v = 0, col="blue", lwd=3, lty=2)
```